# How can get string which seprated by delimeted symbol ( | ) in text file using java?

Tags: java

I having test file in my java project directory which having below content:

HEADER|INPUT|2017|test|1
|Id|Name|

From where I want to update " Id " value from another string "xyz"

"ID" is not static everytime this value gets changed

How can I get particular string using java?

Comment: @user7722867 Won't work. The pipe is a special character in regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `split` function. This will return your string split into the parts, seperated by `|`.

```
var result = "HEADER|INPUT|2017|test|1 |Id|Name|".split("\\|");
// Access an array
// result[0] will be 'Header'
```

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.split() function:

```
String string = "HEADER|INPUT|2017|test|1 |Id|Name|";
String[] parts = string.split("\\|");
String part1 = parts[0]; // HEADER
String part2 = parts[1]; // INPUT
String part3=parts[2]; //2017
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `split()` method here to divide your string as per your requirement.

```
String input= "HEADER|INPUT|2017|test|1 |Id|Name|";
String[] contents = input.split("\\|");
String name = input[6]; 
String id = input[5]; 
String number = input[4]; 
String test = input[3];  
String year = input[2];  
String input = input[1]; 
String header = input[0];
```

For more on [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)